# Input PUK code, when requested

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

**Problem**:

I'm working with a **GPRS** module (the same as in the Arduino GSMShield). In some cases the PUK code is requested, and the **PIN** is thus **locked**. For this I wrote some code (which can be seen under "Software"). This code is based on the documentation of "[GSM PIN Management](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMToolsPinManagement)". The only problem is that the module is telling us that **both** the **PIN & PUK** code is **locked**. The tutorials, however, does not provide an example **how** we should **resolve** this issue from the Arduino itself.

EDIT: When the SIM card is inserted in a smartphone. The PUK code is requested. When the PUK code is provided (and a new PIN) the SIM card is back to normal. But adding the PUK code via the GSM lib. doesn't really work, in contrast to using a smartphone to unlock the PIN code.

**Question**:

- Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this issue? And if it can be done?

**Hardware**:

- Atmega328p
- Quectel M95 (as GPRS module)

**Software**:

```
PINManager.begin();
int pin_query = PINManager.isPIN();
Serial.print(F("Pin Query is: ")); //output: -2
Serial.println(pin_query);
if(pin_query == -1)
{
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println(F("PUK is requested"));
  #endif 

  if(PINManager.checkPUK(PUK_NUMBER, PIN_NUMBER_CORRECT) == 0)
  {
    PINManager.setPINUsed(true); // I also think this must by "false". Both things were tested, none of them worked.

  }
}
```

Comment: If you enter the wrong PUK code 10 times or more, then you will need a new SIM card.

Comment: That's not the case. Because when the SIM is inserted in a smartphone/gsm, the PUK is requested. When adding the PUK code and a new PIN code, the SIM works fine. See the EDIT in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by using **AT commands** instead of the GSM library provided through Arduino.

```
if(sendGPRSCommand(F("AT+CPIN?"),100).equals("AT+CPIN+CPIN:SIMPUKOK")){
    Serial.println(F("PUK is requested, entering it now"));
    String cmd = "AT+CPIN=\"";
    cmd.concat(PUK_NUMBER);
    cmd.concat("\",\"");
    cmd.concat(PIN_NUMBER);
    cmd.concat("\"");
    sendGPRSCommand(cmd,100);
  }
```

This code checks if the PUK code is requested, this is the case when the `pin_query` is -1 or -2 (see question). When the PUK code is requested the new PIN (which is still the same pin as the old one) is given in combination with the PUK code.
The AT commands were found in [this manual](http://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/M95_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.2.pdf).